# what tool lets me create videos like this? text orientated videos

Tags: windows, video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPhFc6GqVdU&feature=relmfu

that's the kind of video I want to make with emphasis on text..I don't know what this type of style is called but it's very eye catching and important information is easily remembered.

Comment: This is known as typography I believe

Answer (score 1):

Hmm,
I did something similar simply creating every frame in Inkscape and then importing to Pinnacle studio - OK, not much comfortable but gives me absolute freedom to control my work. But I think that more advanced video editors should have also better subtitling tools able to do similar videos. Maybe [Lightworks](http://www.lightworksbeta.com/) ...

Answer (score 0):

If I were to make something like that, I would probably use after effects or combustion. Could probably be done in flash or premiere pro, but not very easily.